# Is it possible to 'Hibernate' a Solaris server?

Tags: solaris, hibernate

I need to physically move a server running Solaris to a new location. If I power off the machine and restart it, I would manually need to check if all the required process are running.

Is there any way I can hibernate the machine so that it would just restore its state when I power it on again?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into a proper monitoring/notification system.

Comment: Out of interest, how are you expecting to figure out if all the services have come out of hibernation correctly, even if it were possible? Perhaps a better bet is to come up with a disaster recovery plan, or the monitering/notification idea above first.

Comment: What version of Solaris is this?

Comment: @Shaun: this is Solaris 10. @others: I'm not really a sysadmin. But I think I need to call one :) I was hoping there would be an easy way. Apparently, there isn't.

Comment: Your 'hibernated' server will wake up to find that it's now in a parallel world where none of its assumptions are true anymore. You'll probably delve into a spiral of service restarting activities until they work. It's better to understand your server and the environment and make the necessary changes. It's highly unlikely that this will work without adjustments unless your new environment is exactly the same (which I doubt it is).

Comment: How do you know that if the machine was to crash that all the services are online?  Sounds like you've got some work to do to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the machine - Solaris on some SPARC systems supports suspend-to-disk via the [`sys-suspend` command](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/806-4743/estar-chapter-78/index.html#estar-chapter-proc-113), but Solaris on x86/x64 systems does not.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can find the sys-suspend command alanc mentioned above (test it out on another system if possible).

Alternatively a workaround would be to do a 'ps -ef' listing on the currently running processes on the server. Shutdown, move and restart the system and compare the 'ps' output once you've restarted the server to make sure the same set of processes are running once more. (They will obviously be running under different process id's.)

For a more verbose listing of the full commands that are running you could do

> /usr/ucb/ps -auxwww

which gives the full process command line with parameters and may be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Solaris you can check any process errors after relocation by looking at console when system booting, plus check the /var/adm/messages file and log files under /var/log for any errors.